# How to change direction of items in flexbox-layout

Tags: android, right-to-left, direction, android-api-levels

I want to use [flex-layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) in my android application, but in right to left direction in pre-17 API device. can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this :

```
app:flexDirection="row_reverse"
```

Comment: it wooooooorksss <3<3